# Деление заменить смещением(сдвигом)

Tags: математика, деление

```
int b=(a<<6)+(a<<5)+(a<<2);//умножить на 100
int c=(a<<10)-((a<<4)+(a<<3));//умножить на 1000
int d=(a<<3)+(a<<1);//умножить на 10
```

Подскажете как поделить на 10,100,1000 любого числа `'a'` со смещением(сдвигом)? Целочисленный `int` (остаток от деления не важен).

Comment: Если это в целях оптимизации, то зря, просто напишите `a/100`, компилятор сделает все наилучшем способом.

Comment: Компилятор иногда -тупое животное. Я для себя хочу понять есть ли способ деления по сдвигу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Запросто :)

*0.1<sub>10</sub> = 0.0001100110011001<sub>2</sub>*.
То есть деление на 10 — это *1 / 16 + 1 / 32 + 1 / 256 + 1 / 512 + ...*

Дальше пояснять? :)

А если серьезно - возьмите книгу Уоррена «Алгоритмические трюки для программистов», там есть глава 10, «Целое деление на константы». Там много стоящего.

То же деление на 10:

```
unsigned divu10(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned q, r;
    q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
    q = q + (q >> 4);
    q = q + (q >> 8);
    q = q + (q >> 16);
    q = q >> 3;
    r = n - q * 10;
    return q + ((r + 6) >> 4);
    // return q + (r > 9);
}
```

Comment: а проще можно? Я `asm` в с пытаюсь перевести вменяемо `mov     eax, edi
        mov     edx, 1717986919
        sar     edi, 31
        imul    edx
        sar     edx, 2
        mov     eax, edx
        sub     eax, edi
        ret` У вас длинее.

Comment: Умножение тоже нужно реализовать на сдвигах, иначе смысл теряется. "r = n -( (q<<1)+(q<<3));"  За подсказку где почитать большое спасибо. Дальше постараюсь разобраться сам.

Comment: @AlexBigalo Вы в своем вопросе уже продемонстрировали умножение на 10 через сдвиги; в чем проблема?...